# How to derive a one to one mapping between two discrete sets algorithmically

Tags: algorithms

Given a set of possible coordinates like the below, how would I algorithmically derive a one to one mapping between the two sets (X and Y)? For example I can see 1 <-> A, 2 <-> B, 3 <-> D, 4 <-> C and 5 <-> E is a one to one mapping below, but I am interested in how I can define an algorithm such that it will provide me with a mapping (or more than one, or indeed show one doesn't exist) given any pair of sets and their "possible" coordinates.

I'm not really sure where to start with this, any pointers would be appreciated.

[image: graph]

Comment: Simple: Step 1. Guess a mapping (There are $n!$ such) Step 2. Verify if the mapping is valid. This is an NP-Algorithm for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution here http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/

The problem I'm having is actually a special case of the Maximum Flow Problem

`Given a graph which represents a flow network where every edge has a capacity. Also given two vertices source ‘s’ and sink ‘t’ in the graph, find the maximum possible flow from s to t with following constraints:

a) Flow on an edge doesn't exceed the given capacity of the edge.

b) Incoming flow is equal to outgoing flow for every vertex except s and t.`

Which can be solved with the Ford Fulkerson algorithm.